# Linking header files in codeblocks

Tags: codeblocks

So I've written code in OpenCV which contains 2 header files using Code::Blocks. When I compile the files, there are no errors except two "undefined reference..." errors which occur because I have used functions that I have declared in the header files. I assumed that code blocks automatically linked the header files? I have used the "#include.." to include the header files at the top of the programs so not sure what the problem could be. Anyone have any idea? Thanks.

Comment: which ones are missing, please ?

Comment: nothing is missing I don't think. Everything is there, just unsure how to link the header files with the source files as I assumed CodeBlocks just did that automatically?

Comment: anyone got any answers?

Comment: You don't link header files, you link multiple compilation units. A header file isn't always a compilation unit (it is in your case it seems). In the "Build Options" menu (in the Linker tab), you should click the "Add" button to tell the linker about the required files (.a/.so/.dll/...).

Answer (score 4):

I was having a similar problem, but happened upon a solution

1. Click the "Project" tab, it's in the top right side.
2. Within the "Project" tab click the "Add Files..." option.
3. Highlight your Header file and any other files associated with your header file, like if you put your header files definitions in a .cpp file.
4. Compile and Run.

Hopefully this helps, it worked for me but our issues could be different.

Comment: I've been looking for an answer to this for about 3 hours and this one worked. I don't know why it didn't just compile itself. My code was all correct and I guess doing this just updated Codeblocks or something?