# Why are header files not recognized in Code::Blocks

Tags: header, codeblocks

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "CON8INC.H"
#include "CON8DEF.H"
#include "CON8FUNC.H" // function declarations / prototypes


/**************** begin main ***************/

main()
{
    char choice = ' ';

    set_up();         // initialize the arrays

    // other stuff goes here
return 0;
}  /* END OF MAIN */
```

All source.c files and header files were added to the C::B project using the IDE.
None of the local header files are checked for compile or link.
The CON8DEF.H file contains this line:     void set_up(void);
and similar lines for each function in the source.c files.
When I run Build and Run in the IDE, I get this message for each function called by
main.c:      undefined reference to 'set_up'
What do I need to do get the headers recognized by the source.c code?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53842686/17635987 So you say you have already done these steps?

Comment: Yes. Many times and have also reinstalled Code::Blocks and recreated the project

Comment: Is there a way to manually create a path to the single directory containing the source and header files?   The problem may be greater than that:  I have commented out 3 of the functions in the header file and listed them between the includes and the call to main.  I still get the undefined reference to all 3 of those functions as well as the others in the header file.

Comment: void set_up(void);
    void convert_12PointsTest(void);
    void convert_coasts1(void);

Comment: In the comment above I should have said I have comment out 3 of the declarations (not functions) in the header file

Comment: Problem Resolved:  I  uninstalled Code:Blocks and then downloaded it from FossHUB and installed in the C:\   I also had to change the path to the complier from the Programs/users directory to the C:\MinGW